# <hr> element rendering wrong in inverted ways between JsFiddle and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, jsfiddle

The problem im having is that I try to render a straight line between a left/right border. But the behavior is unexpected.
[Here is the JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/3pag5wL9/1/) showing the line rendering ALMOST correct. The problem is that the line should line up against the right border but now leave a small space. However if you open this file in Chrome you will see that the line overshoots the right border and continues endlessly to the right.  What is causing this?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    table.vf {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 800px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td.vf {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 40px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
}
td.edges {
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
}
td span {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
hr {
    border: none;
    color: blue;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
hr {
    margin:10px 0;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="vf">
    <tr>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
        <td class="vf"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="vf"></td>
        <td colspan="10" class="vf edges">
            <hr/><span><a href="#">TEST</a></span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tables are not longer commonly used for layout for this very reason, they are unpredictable. Use DIV's

Comment: To clarify- do you want to know `What is causing this?`, or do you have a desired outcome in mind?

Comment: @Mattigins There is nothing unpredictable here. That's how absolute positioned elements work. It has very little to do with it being a table.

Answer (score -1):

The reason its doing this is because you have the table width at 800px and then you have the hr positioned absolute and width 100%, therefore its not going to listen to the td its inside. Add position relative to the td like below;

```
td.vf {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative; //// Added style
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: That won't work. `position: relative` is not possible on table cells. It's effects are undefined in the standards and doesn't work in most browsers.

Comment: Wrong, It works perfectly, i have cross browser checked, please test before you mark down my answer.

Comment: What browser? doesnt distort in firefox or chrome, are you using a special font, throught fontface or something?